# Stop thread execution/terminate immediately in Python 2.7

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt

I am designing a QT based application designed in Python. The application has following two buttons:

1. Move Robot
2. Stop Robot

The robot takes some time to move from one point to another. Hence I invoke a new thread to control robot movement to prevent the GUI from becoming unresponsive. Below the move function:

```
from threading import Thread
from thread import start_new_thread

def move_robot(self):
    def move_robot_thread(points):
        for point in points:
            thread = Thread(target=self.robot.move, args=(point,))
            thread.start()
            thread.join()
    start_new_thread(move_robot_thread, (points,))
```

The above function works well. In order to stop the robot motion, I need to stop the execution of the above threads. Please see the complete code below:

```
from python_qt_binding.QtGui import QPushButton

self.move_robot_button = QPushButton('Move Robot')
self.move_robot_button.clicked.connect(self.move_robot)
self.move_robot_button = QPushButton('Stop Robot')
self.move_robot_button.clicked.connect(self.stop_robot)
self.robot = RobotControllerWrapper()

from threading import Thread
from thread import start_new_thread

def move_robot(self):
    def move_robot_thread(points):
        for point in points:
            thread = Thread(target=self.robot.move, args=(point,))
            thread.start()
            thread.join()
    start_new_thread(move_robot_thread, (points,))

def stop_robot(self):
    pass

class RobotControllerWrapper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.robot_controller = RobotController()

    def move(self, point):
        while True:
            self._robot_controller.move(point)
            current_location = self.robot_controller.location()
            if current_location - point < 0.0001:
                break
```

How to stop the execution of the thread? Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

Using a flag should be enough:

```
self.run_flag = False   # init the flag
...

def move_robot(self):
    def move_robot_thread(points):
        self.run_flag = True   # set to true before starting the thread
        ...

def stop_robot(self):
    self.robot.stop()

class RobotControllerWrapper():
    ...
    def move(self, point):
        while self.run_flag == True:   # check the flag here, instead of 'while True'
            ...

    def stop(self):
        self.run_flag = False   # set to false to stop the thread
```